# How can i use a Jenkins to copy files to S3 bucket?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3

Jenkins has a plugin , S3 Publisher, can this be used to copy a file to a particular s3 bucket.
I have a file on the local drive but when i configure the source in the plugin as "c:\test\testfile.txt"   it doesnt seem to like it , says it cant find the file.

Can i transfer files with this plugin or is there a plugin which can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could very easily install the AWS CLI into the Jenkins machine, set up the profile to connect to you AWS account, then use `aws s3 cp` commands to copy upload and download files from s3 without using any plugins. This method is more future-proof since you don't have to worry about any changes happening from the s3 side that may break the plugin, or having the plugin get outdated.